# Ayuda hacer este problema de Arreglos

Tags: c++

Programe la función **int primos_suma(int *A, int n)** que rellena el arreglo **int A[n]** de los primeros n primos y devuelve la suma de los elementos de A. Utilice apuntadores.

Answer (score -1):

## Ojalá que te sirva

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 15

int primos_suma(int*, int);

int main()
{
     //////Recuerda que si n es mayor que el tamaño del arreglo, mostrara numeros aleatorios/////
    int* a = new int[SIZE];
    cout<<primos_suma(a,SIZE);
    cout<<"\n\nValores: ";
    for(int i = 0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        cout<<*(a+i)<<" ";
    }
    delete a;
 }

int primos_suma(int* array,const int n)
{
    int suma = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    float div;
    unsigned short int num = 1;
    int cont = 0;
    //////Algoritmo principal (para los primos)///////
    while(total <= n)
    {
        cont = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<=num;i++)
        {
            float div = static_cast<float>(num)/i;
            int aux = static_cast<int>(div);
            float res = div - aux;
            if(res == 0){cont++;}
        }

        if(cont <= 2)
        {
            *(array+pos) = num;
            pos++;
            total ++;
        }
        num++;
    }
    ////////Hallando suma////////
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        suma += *(array+i);
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta sí se acompaña de un poco de explicación ayudaría de mejor manera.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio para mi prograna...